# Cómo limpiar la Consola de RStudio y los Terminales RStudio y macOS

Tags: r, poo, terminal, rstudio, ascii

Encontré este [enlace en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r-and-rstudio) sobre el asunto y ahí explican varios métodos para limpiar la consola de RStudio.

No obstante en **Matlab** y **Octave** sólo se escribe `clc` y se limpia el ambiente de trabajo y realmente estoy acostumbrado a eso.

En cambio si quisiera lograr lo mismo en R

```
clc <- function() cat("\014")
```

Al escribir en la consola `clc` se imprime `function() cat("\014")` en tal sentido, tendría que escribir `clc()` y para eso necesariamente hay que usar la tecla shift.

> Existe alguna forma de limpiar la consola de RStudio, personalizando el nombre que uno desea.

Sumado a lo anterior si se emplea los alimentadores de hoja: `cat("\014")` o `cat("\f")` en los terminales de RStudio y macOS cuando ya se ejecutó previamente [R.app](https://cran.r-project.org/), se produce sólo un salto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Cómo lograr que lo anterior no suceda y cómo establecer una función que reconozca si estoy en la Consola RStudio o en los Terminales RStudio o macOS

Comment: con CONTROL+L borras la info que tienes en consola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe una manera de que `clc` limpie la consola de R si hacemos lo siguiente:

```
clc <- 0
class(clc) <- 'limpiar'
print.limpiar <- function(rObject) cat("\014")
```

Cómo trabaja el código de arriba

Cuando escribes algo previamente definido en R (una variable en este caso), R interpreta que se quiere imprimir -en este caso `clc` fue definido inicialmente como una clase del tipo "numeric", pudo ser también una "matrix"-

Luego se crea el método para la clase "limpiar" como `print.limpiar()`

Entonces cualquier objeto -*función, variable, etc.*- que provenga de la clase que sea del tipo "limpiar" -la única que hay es `clc`- al momento de ser imprimida no imprimirá nada, pero ejecutará `cat("\014")`

Por tanto, una vez ejecutadas las tres líneas de arriba, sólo tienes que escribir

```
clc
```

y la consola de R estará limpia.

Si estamos en los terminales RStudio y macOS la tercera línea (`print.limpiar <- function(rObject) cat("\014")`) debería ser cambiada por lo siguiente:

```
print.limpiar <- function(rObject) cat(c("\033[2J","\033[H"))
```

Está función no sólo limpiará el terminal respectivo también colocará el cursor en la parte superior izquierda del mismo ya que la mayoría de terminales soporta el [código de escape ANSI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI)
siendo

- `"\033"`: Esc
- `"[2J"`: Borra toda la pantalla
- `"[1;1H"` o `"[H"`: columna 1 y fila 1 de la pantalla, aunque prefiero
  `"H"` porque me recuerda a "Home" o "Inicio" en las páginas web.

Ahora si se desea algo dinámico para que el código reconozca si estamos en R.app o en RStudio, **R** cuenta con una función `commandArgs`, para el caso **macOS** la carpeta default de la aplicación es: `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R"`

La implementación completa está aquí en mi github: [clc.R](https://github.com/HubertRonald/clcR)

> **NOTA:** El script **clcR** compartido no ha sido probado en: Linux, Windows, Ubuntu. Si intentas ejecutarlo en alguno de estos sistemas operativos u otros por favor déjalo en la caja de comentarios para actualizar **clcR**.
>
> **CONSIDERACIÓN:** Asimismo en dicho script **(clcR)** la clase `limpiar` es denominada como `cleanup` y el parámetro `rObject` definido para su método, corresponde a `cleanupObject`.

Comment: Hola Hubert, dejame agregar que también podrías hacer `cat("\f")`, el `\f` o código 14 de la tabla Ascii, se conoce como Form Feed o page eject. Si usas Rstudio, también puedes usar `<CTR><L>`. El único problema que tiene esto, es cuando el cursor esta puesto en una línea no vacía, limpia todo menos esta línea. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas facil es usar la libreria KeyboardSimulator par simular "ctrl + l"

```
library(KeyboardSimulator)
keybd.press("Ctrl", hold = T)
keybd.press("l")
keybd.release("Ctrl")
```