# Cómo puedo imprimir en la misma línea reemplazando o borrando lo que he impreso antes?

Tags: python

Quisiera saber cómo puedo imprimir en la misma línea reemplazando una impresión previa; es decir, quisiera imprimir en el mismo sitio (posicionar el curso una y otra vez en el mismo punto para reemplazar una salida anterior con una nueva).

Tengo este código, como verán habrá una secuencia en la que el 1 se mueve desde el inicio de la lista al final, pero al imprimir imprime todas las etapas de manera vertical y yo quisiera que en pantalla aparezca la primera y en el mismo sitio aparezca la segunda y así sucesivamente pero que vaya reemplazando en pantalla la etapa anterior y no que imprima una debajo de otra. He intentado añadir `end="\b"` y `end="\r"`, pero no he obtenido nada.

Espero me haya hecho entender, gracias de antemano.

```
import time
x=["1","0","0","0"]

for i in range(len(x)):
    x.insert((i+1),"1")
    x.remove("1")
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta

Se puede emplear el `os` y usar la expresión "printf \033c" que de acuerdo al código ASCII es de escape, esto también lo he usado en este post con más detalle:
[Cómo limpiar la Consola de RStudio y los Terminales RStudio y macOS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/237112/c%C3%B3mo-limpiar-la-consola-de-rstudio-y-los-terminales-rstudio-y-macos)

Por tanto el código quedaría así

```
import os
import time

x=["1","0","0","0"]

for i in range(len(x)):
    if i<len(x):
      os.system("printf '\033c'")
    x.insert((i+1),"1")
    x.remove("1")
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

El código en [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PunctualElementaryDemoware)

## Esto fue lo primero que se contestó

De acuerdo a la documentación (en inglés) de **Python3** la función [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) tiene el siguiente parámetro por defecto `end='\n'`, en tal sentido, cada vez que se imprime en el bucle `for` con dicho parámetro`'\n'` lo realiza en una nueva línea.

Lo único que hay que hacer es definir el parámetro `end` con un espacio en blanco en este caso, para que todo quede en la misma línea `end=' '`.

Por tanto así quedaría el código:

```
x = ["1", "0", "0", "0"]

for i in range(len(x)):
    x.insert(i+1,"1")
    x.remove("1")
    print(x, end=" ")

# Se imprime
# ['1', '0', '0', '0'] ['0', '1', '0', '0'] ['0', '0', '1', '0'] ['0', '0', '0', '1']
```

También quería añadir que si se llama de nuevo `print` sin el parámetro `end`, lo imprimirá la primera vez en la misma línea, en dicho caso agregar después del `print` del bucle `for` `print("\n", "lo que se va imprimir")` sólo una vez.

```
print("\n",x)
print(x)
print(123)

# ['0', '0', '0', '1']
# ['0', '0', '0', '1']
# 123
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta. No es lo que quería explicar, imprimir horizontalmente lo puedo hacer fácilmente como usted lo ha dicho. Pero lo que yo quiero es algo así.                                                                                                     [1 0 0 0]   ## Después de un segundo quisiera que en pantalla aparezca la segunda etapa                                                                                                    [0 1 0 0 ] sin que aparezca la anterior.

Comment: Algo como: se imprime la primera etapa, luego desaparece y aparece solo la segunda, luego se borra, desaparece, reemplaza o como sea pero aparee solo la siguiente siguiente y así hasta el fin. Espero me haya hecho entender, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ok @tony ya más claro lo agregué a mi respuesta y mantuve lo anterior para que se entienda estos comentarios que me has hecho

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a tu pregunta, la manera más sencilla es crear una función en la cual manipules los parámetros de la función `print`, esto con el fin de simular una función del tipo `gotoxy(x,y)`, a continuación adjunto tu código del programa agregando la función que posiciona el cursor exactamente en el mismo lugar de la impresión anterior y me funciona perfectamente.

```
import time
x=["1","0","0","0"]

def gotoxy(x,y):
    print ("%c[%d;%df" % (0x1B, y, x), end='')

for i in range(len(x)):
    x.insert((i+1),"1")
    x.remove("1")
    gotoxy(0,4)
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Puedes ejecutarlo en línea en el siguiente enlace: [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PowderblueGrippingJavadoc)

Igualmente si deseas indagar más en el tema, te dejo [este enlace](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning#Python).

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Galoget

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: De nada @Tony, un gusto, por favor no te olvides de marcar mi respuesta como la correcta, saludos.